# @Inject object null: Play dependency injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.1

I instantiated using dependency injection in my controller class. When i try to use that object using @inject annotation elsewhere, i get null value. Here is my code skeleton.

```
@singleton
class ServiceClient(ws: WSClient, config: Configuration) {
 def get response() {...}
}

class App @Inject()(client: ServiceClient) extends Controller {

   def getItems = Action  {
     Obj()
   }
}

case class Obj() {

  @Inject
  var client: ServiceClient = _
  def doStuff() {
    client.getResponse() //client is null so get null pointer exception.
    ....
  }
}
```

The @Inject in Obj never seems to be working. and my client object is always null. (I do not want to pass client as param to Obj.)  My expectation was that ServiceClient object created in controller should have been injected in Obj(). What did i do wrong?

**update**

Injecting Obj to the controller, is not an option. (In my app Obj are instantiated at run time my some complicated rule, using reflection).Also i dont want to have the constructor injection in the Obj.  **I am looking for field injection of ServiceClient outside of the controller.**

**update2**

I was able to solve the problem using

```
var client: ServiceClient = play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[ServiceClient])
```

in the Obj class.
However, play.api.Play.current is deprecated in play 2.5 so i am still kind of stuck with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject dependency into the class instance without asking about it the DI framework. In your code you manually instantiate `Obj` which means the dependency injection magic is not happening. In order to inject dependency to `Obj` class its instantiation should be handled by the DI framework. What you can do here is:

1. Inject `ServiceClient` to either `Obj` constructor or filed:

   ```
   class Obj @Inject() (client: ServiceClient) {
     //
   }
   ```

   It makes sense to use simple class instead of case class because case class sounds more like "data" class with immutable data inside rather than service or some helper class. Actually, your current definition of `Obj` class should work.
2. Inject `Obj` and (or, depending on your needs) `ServiceClient` to your App class:

   ```
   class App @Inject()(obj: Obj, client: ServiceClient) extends Controller {
     def getItems = Action  {
       obj.doStuff()
     }
   }
   ```

I'd recommend you to read more about dependency injection and Guice framework which is used in Play by default. [Guice wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation)

Comment: thanks. can you elaborate more on how do i inject dependency into class instance.

Comment: The flow is actually depends on DI framework. In Guice the common pattern is 1. define a module (class that extends AbstractModule) which defines binding for classes (interfaces) and their implementations (binding can also be done using annotations), 2. create an injector for that module `val injector = Guice.createInjector(new YourModule())`. 3. Ask injector for a specific class instance `injector.getInstance(classOf[Obj])`. So the instantiation is handled by Guice. Also have a look at [Play docs for DI](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection).

Comment: In Play you normally do not create injector yourself but modules are commonly used. Note that you need to enable module in Play config (`application.conf`)

Comment: i dont want to inject ServiceClient in the constructor of Obj. I think what i am looking for is how to do  field injection of serviceClient in Obj class.  can u give some code examples. thanks.

Comment: Just as you defined should work `@Inject var client: ServiceClient = _` but still, you need to let Guice instantiate `Obj` which can be done just by injecting `Obj` to the controller.

Comment: I cant inject Obj to the controller. (That is part of the design, and outside the scope of the question)  Updated the question. In that case can i inject ServiceClient instance in the Obj ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113666/discussion-between-konquestor-and-yahor).

Comment: I guess you can. But then you need to use Play injector to get instance of `Obj` class like `val obj = play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[Obj])`.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using System.currentTimeMillis play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[ServiceClient]), however in play 2.5 play.api.Play.current is deprecated, so not sure what to use instead.

Comment: In Play 2.5 you need to inject `Application` to the class where you need to use it.